# How does the body measure dehydration?

Tags: human-biology, homeostasis

What, physically, does the body do to measure it? I assume it's measured by how how turgid or plasmolysed certain 'sample cells' are, or water concentration in the blood,

- What *is* the way they use to measure it?
- What do the receptor cells that do the measuring actually *do* that is variable with water concentration, etc.

Comment: This article reviews the subject but I can't access it. http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v9/n7/full/nrn2400.html perhaps someone has access to nature neuroscience and can relay the details, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia [entry on thirst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirst):

> In the mammalian brain, the posterior surface of the hypothalamus
>   forms the front wall of the third ventricle (a cerebrospinal
>   fluid-filled cavity) and clusters of cells (osmoreceptors) on this
>   surface, notably in the organum vasculosum of the lamina terminalis
>   (OVLT) and subfornical organ (SFO), signal this cellular dehydration
>   to other parts of the brain, and thirst is experienced. Destruction of
>   this part of the hypothalamus in humans and other animals results in
>   partial or total loss of desire to drink even with extremely high salt
>   concentration in the extracellular fluids.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmoreceptor)

The [entry on osmoreceptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmoreceptor) says in part:

> When the osmotic pressure of blood changes (i.e. it is more or less
>   dilute), water diffusion into and out of the osmoreceptor cells
>   changes. That is, they expand when the blood plasma is more dilute and
>   contract with higher concentration.

It also describes how the kidney measures chlorine anion flow through some nephrons, which triggers a cascade of messenger molecules resulting in increased blood levels of the hormone angiotensin, which also results in thirst messages originating in the hypothalamus.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirst)Derek A. Denton (8 June 2006). The primordial emotions: the dawning of consciousness. Oxford University Press. pp. 118–19. ISBN 978-0-19-920314-7.

[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmoreceptor)Walter F., PhD. Boron (2005). Medical Physiology: A Cellular And Molecular Approach. Elsevier/Saunders. ISBN 1-4160-2328-3. Page 872

Comment: How do osmoreceptors work? That is, how and by what is the 'swollenness' of the osmoreceptors measured, and how does this turn into an electrical signal?

Answer (score 1):

Dehydration results in decreased blood volume (hypovolemia) and in slight decrease of blood pressure. The body recognises dehydration by these ways:

1. Baroreceptors in the aorta detect the drop of blood pressure - this results in activation of the sympathetic nerves and the release of adrenaline from the adrenal medulla - this leads to constriction of the arteries ad increased heart rate.
2. Volume receptors in the heart atria detect hypovolemia - this result in the secretion of the antidiuretic hormone from the pituitary gland - this results in water retention in the kidneys.
3. Osmoreceptors in the hypothalamus detect increased blood osmolality - this triggers the release of the hormone ADH.
4. Juxtaglomerular apparatus in the kidneys detect decreased perfusion, what results in the renin-angiotensin-aldosterone release cascade, which results in water retention in the kidneys.

All these mechanisms are activated in the compensated [hypovolemic shock](http://www.ehealthstar.com/hypovolemia/hypovolemic-shock).